# Adding height data to polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, altitude

I want to place a polyline at the correct altitude in QGIS.

Is that possible and how do I do this?

What I have is a polyline (railroad) and I want to add information on the electrics above the railroad.

Say, the electrics are z meters above the rails, how do I get this data into the attribute table?

I want to use this information to calculate the number of trees that can reach the electrics if they fall. And yes, I get that they would reach the rails even if they aren't tall enough to reach the electrics.

---

I've tried to use the tip I got in the comments below, but it was a bit too complicated for me, I simply don't understand how to do it.

I just want to add values to the z-coordinat (of a polyline).

Answer (score 0):

You can use GRASS 3D data there is more than 300 GRASS modules are available.

See http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html

Comment: Thanks, good tip. The problem is, I have never used GRASS, and as you said - there are hundreds of modules. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: @SoS You should read following documents then you can get ideas about how to make 3D features using GRASS Model 7.               http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/wxGUI.Nviz.html

Comment: When I try to use nviz, I get 'Module nviz not found'? I use QGIS 2.0.1.